# Returning an array in onOpen function

Tags: javascript, laravel, websocket, ratchet

I am currently writing a chat application. So far users can send each other messages and I am able to store the messages in my database. Now I want to show the messages which are stored in the database in my onOpen function, when the user opens up the page to message another user.

This is what my onOpen function looks like:

```
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {

        $query =  $conn->httpRequest->getUri()->getQuery();

        preg_match_all('!\d+!', $query, $matches);

        $my_id = $matches[0][0];

        $friend_id = $matches[0][1];

        $conn->resourceId = $my_id;

        $this->users[$conn->resourceId] = $conn;

        $messages = Private_message::where([

            ['user1',$my_id],
            ['user2',$friend_id]

        ])->orWhere([

            ['user1',$friend_id],
            ['user2',$my_id]

        ])->get()->toArray();

    }
```

I want to return the `$messages` array to my `privateChat.blade.php` view so I can print them out.

Iv'e tried to do `return view('privateChat',['messages' => $messages]);` and `@dd($messages)` in my `privateChat.blade.php` but it says the variable is undefined. 
I also tried `return $messages` and print them out in my onopen js function but it doesn't work. What is the right way to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you can see you are not returning anything back to view

so

```
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
{

    $query =  $conn->httpRequest->getUri()->getQuery();

    preg_match_all('!\d+!', $query, $matches);

    $my_id = $matches[0][0];

    $friend_id = $matches[0][1];

    $conn->resourceId = $my_id;

    $this->users[$conn->resourceId] = $conn;

    $messages = Private_message::where([

        ['user1',$my_id],
        ['user2',$friend_id]

    ])->orWhere([

        ['user1',$friend_id],
        ['user2',$my_id]

    ])->get()->toArray();

   $viewShareVariables = compact('messages');

   return view('privateChat',$viewShareVariables);

}
```

If any issues kindly comment below

Comment: Tried printing it out with `@dd($viewShareVariables)` and it gives me an error of `Undefined variable: viewShareVariables`

Comment: i think you misunderstood it you can try `@dd($messages)` which is passed into the `compact()` and passed as a ***second argument in view helper***

Comment: The problem was that I returned my `privateChat` view in a different function already and passed variables to it, so returning it once again didn't work since i was already in that view. Instead I tried passing the `$messages` array with those other variables and it worked.